# How to make hitTest, Collision Detection Functionality in Android

Tags: java, android

I have three small ImageView on Screen/View. OnTouch and onTouchMove I have to detect that the Touch/Mouse has collide the ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

Use it for getting it.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int action=(int)event.getAction();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

event.getAction();
return three value.
0-MouseDown
1-MouseUp
2-MouseDrag
```

using this you can determine Touch/Mouse or collide.

Comment: Hi DynamicMind

I am drawing using Touch/Fingure touch , during Fingure move, I have to detect that particular ImageView has been touched by Fingure so that I can delete/scale/rotate it.



Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick( View v )
     {
           System.out.println( "touched" );
     }//met
});
```

Comment: Your above mentioened is only for get touch event , but not for suitable to detect collision of two or more imageView.